# Posting JSON to WebAPI2 function

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code in an MVC app controller to send some data to be stored in an Archive table using EF6 via a WebAPI2 call.

I'm getting a "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type" even though I'm setting to POST and the api call is defined to accept only POST.

What in the world am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
ArchiveUploadModel.ArchiveUpload obj = new ArchiveUploadModel.ArchiveUpload();

obj.LT = LT;
obj.PID = PID.ToString();
obj.Title = "Ex Review";
obj.HTML = message.Body; // the HTML is a rendered HTML email message 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.HTML))
{
    HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/MyApp/api/UploadToArchive") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
}
using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

This is the code for my WebAPI call:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/UploadToArchive")]
[EnableCors("http://example.com",                      // Origin
            "Accept, Origin, Content-Type, Options",   // Request headers
            "POST",                                    // HTTP methods
            PreflightMaxAge = 600                      // Preflight cache duration
)]
public IHttpActionResult UploadToArchive(ArchiveUpload upload)
{
    string HTML = upload.HTML;
    string Title = upload.Title;
    string LT = upload.LT;
    string lt = getLT(upload.PID); // essentially secure checking to see if it matches passed LT.
    if (lt == LT)
    {
        // Upload the file to the archive using the ArchiveRepository's UpdateArchive() function:
        _ArchiveRepository.UpdateArchive(HTML, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Title), "", upload.PID);
        return Ok(PID);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid LT");
    }
}
```

ArchiveUpload model definition in both applications:

```
public class ArchiveUpload
{
    public string LT { get; set; }
    public string PID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string HTML { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This may be of use. HttpClient is easier to work with than HttpWebRequest.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

My money would be on some form-formatting issue.

Comment: Post as answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better try to use the Microsoft Http Client Libraries. You can install it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) you find examples calling Web API using different HTTP verbs

Comment: Did this but having another issue that is not related.